# Why am I only receiving the first address byte? (I2C Protocol)

Tags: c, avr, i2c

Expecting the slave to ACKnowledge and return data, but it does not. [This is my protocol](https://gist.github.com/SensationSama/c60253c8553caf29f7353a725ee42fc4). [This is my Datasheet](https://ams.com/eng/content/download/686523/1787697/file/iAQ-core_Datasheet_EN_v1.pdf)

The datasheet mentions "The slave will answer by sending bytes with MSB first. Byte0 and byte1 contain the
prediction value. All bytes are acknowledged by the master."

**Edit:** [Source Library](https://github.com/g4lvanix/I2C-master-lib)

Also FYI I'm on an Arduino Fio but I am not inheriting the Arduino library.

```
    #include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uart.h>
#include <i2c_master.h>

#define LED PB5

#define I2C_READ 0x5A

char buffer[1];

//char data[9];
uint16_t val = 0;
uint8_t status = 0;


void getVal()
{
  if(i2c_start(I2C_READ))
    {
        uart_puts("Start ");

        val = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8; 
        val |= i2c_read_ack();

    status = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_nack());

      i2c_stop();

    } else
  {
        uart_puts("Error");

        i2c_stop();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
  init_uart(57600);
  i2c_init();

  DDRB = _BV(5);

    for(;;)
    {



        getVal();

        itoa(status, buffer, 10); //convert decimal to string base 10
        uart_puts(buffer);

  PORTB = 0xFF;
  _delay_ms(500);
  PORTB = 0x00;
  _delay_ms(500);
}
return 0;   /* never reached */
```

}

---

Edit Revised:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uart.h>
#include <i2c_master.h>

#define LED PB5

#define I2C_READ 0x5A

char buffer[10];

//char data[9];
uint16_t val = 0;
uint8_t status = 0;


{
  if(!i2c_start(I2C_READ))
    {
        uart_puts("Error");

        i2c_stop();

    } else
    {
        uart_puts("Start ");
        i2c_start((IAQ_ADDR << 1) + 1); //i2c_start(0xB5);

        val = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8; 
        val |= i2c_read_ack();

        status = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_nack());

        i2c_stop();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
  init_uart(57600);
  i2c_init();

  DDRB = _BV(5);

    for(;;)
    {

      getVal();

            itoa(status, buffer, 10); //convert decimal to string base 10
            uart_puts(buffer);

      PORTB = 0xFF;
      _delay_ms(500);
      PORTB = 0x00;
      _delay_ms(500);
    }
    return 0;   /* never reached */
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but hardware related problems are hard to impossible to diagnose as we cannot replicate the hardware. Also there is no guarantee your hardware works properly. Just a hint: use a Scope/LA to check bus.

Comment: Looks like you've linked to a local copy of the datasheet. Does this one look right? https://ams.com/eng/content/.../file/iAQ-core_Datasheet_EN_v1.pdf

Comment: I fixed the link, thanks!

Comment: `buffer` has size `1`, so your `itoa` overflows the buffer.

Comment: Looks like I have the same issue but only with LTC2943 and LTC2946: despites of the register requested they send me always data from 00h, and if I continue reading further I can read the whole dataset but always only starting from 00h register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to tell without having details of the i2c library that is being used, but the one thing I'd be checking first is the `i2c_start(I2C_READ)`.

The i2c address provided in the datasheet is `0x5a` as you've put in your macro. But the first byte also contains the read/write flag as the least significant bit. The `i2c_start()` function has to be putting `0xb5` onto the bus (i.e. `(0x5a << 1) + 1` for a read)

If `i2c_start()` is not, then your slave device is not actually being addressed and so won't ack.

Comment: When do I implement this shift? Changing the address results in an error.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behaviour.  You have declared `buffer` as:

```
char buffer[1];
```

That's an array of one single character.  The only null-terminated string you can possibly store there is *empty string* (i.e. where `buffer[0] == '\0'`).  But you are using it to convert integers to strings.

You need to make the buffer large enough to hold the largest string you expect to store in it, including the terminator.

Comment: Nice catch. This was most likely part of the issue. The problem persists, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your root issue is here. What are the symptoms you are having? What kind of output do you have on your UART?

As others have said, your `buffer` variable is too small to hold anything of value as a C string. `itoa` ([AVR libc entry](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdlib_1gaa571de9e773dde59b0550a5ca4bd2f00.html)) usually provides a null-terminated string, so you'll need to be at least big enough for all the characters as well as the null value. You may be having an issue overflowing the buffer, in which case you should have a simple solution.

Your use of `uin8_t` means you should be allocating enough space for the representation of up to 255. You need 3 characters to represent the full range, as well as one character for the null character. Change your code to read `char buffer[4];` and see if that improves the issues you are having.

If the I2C protocol implementation is in error, that will be harder to diagnose without accurate information on where the error is. A logic analyser should help here if you have access to one.

**EDIT:**

I just took a look at the datasheet and your method of `i2c_start(0x5A)` with consecutive `i2c_read_ack()`s seems to be correct. However, based on your linked protocol, you are probably just seeing "Error" on your UART as `i2c_start()` returns `0` for a successful start transaction and you check `if(i2c_start(I2C_READ))` when you should be testing for `if(! i2c_start(I2C_READ))` in `getVal()`.

You also seem to have some unnecessary `uint8_t` casts based on your linked i2c_master.c gist. I'd suggest just using the Arduino IDE if this really is an Arduino compatible board and see if you can get a simple I2C example to work with the sensor to prove out your access methodology.

Comment: uart_puts is returning 90. I'm getting 'start' not 'error'.

Comment: Your now-linked source library says to start your I2C transaction with `I2C_start(SLAVE_ADDRESS+I2C_READ);`, so your 0x5A (or 90) is not enough to start the transaction. As mentioned by @Andrew Edgecombe, you need to shift the 7-bit address left by 1 bit, and add 1 for a read. Try `I2C_start(0xB5)` and see if that helps. Using only 0x5A causes an attempt to _write_ to I2C address 0x2D (45).

Comment: Sam, that call doesn't work. I managed to get it working, but its awkward. First I call IF(i2c_start(IAQ_ADDR)) {i2c_start((IAQ_ADDR << 1) + 1);}

Comment: So you've done, basically, `if(i2c_start(0x5A)) { i2c_start(0xB5);}`. The reason this is working is because--back to my original point--the `i2c_start(0x5A)` call is failing, returning a value of `1` and causing you to enter the `if` statement (1 evalutes to true in C). That then allows the call to `i2c_start(0xB5)` to occur and that call actually works. Your `if` condition needs to be negated if you mean to test for success of the `i2c_start()` function.

Comment: Sam, thank you very much for bringing this to my attention. However, `i2c_start(0xb5)` does not work on its own.

Comment: I've edited the original post, does this look correct to you? I will try to test with the board first thing tomorrow. Last time I checked: i2c_start(0xB5) did not work without the prior start method call to 0x5a.

Answer (score 0):

For I2C, it is very important to have pull-up resistors on both SDA and SCL pins. If these are not present, the bus will always read low or floating voltage. I do not know the AVR hardware enough to know how it would behave, but I would expect the  "// check if the start condition was successfully transmitted" to fail if this is the case.

In general when developing for hardware like this, I do recommend to have a logic analyzer. It can help when you are blind to what the hardware bus actually does.

An example of such device is https://www.saleae.com/ ,but multiple vendors and/or open projects exists.

Comment: I am using pullup resistors. Yeah, a logic analyzer might be wise.